# Response.data is empty when I hit api using Axios.create but it gives response when I use axios.post

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I am trying to hit API with axios but response.data variable is empty. While using axios.create but when i directly hit API with axios.post. It works fine. I want to get the response through axios.create. Here is my axios create code

```
const client = axios.create({
baseURL: BASE_URL,
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Accept": "application/json",
},
});
```

And my method for post request is:

```
export const postRequest = (url, payload = {}) => client.post(url, payload);
```

And when i request i call this method:

```
  const res = await postRequest('/login', body)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this. I am using this test API https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ you can cross-check my snippet response with the mentioned URL.

```js
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
});


client({
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': '/todos/1'
}).then((res) => console.log(res.data))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`axios.create` returns a `client` that has the property `.request`, not `.post`

Example from https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/create-post

```js
const client = axios.create({
  url: '/post',
  baseURL: 'https://httpbin.org',
  method: 'POST',
  timeout: 1000
});

let res = await client .request({
  data: {
    name: 'Masteringjs.io',
    email: 'Masteringjs@io'
  }
});

res.data.json // ↓
// { email: 'Masteringjs@io', name: 'Masteringjs.io' }
```

So your code would look like this:

```js
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
  },
  method: "POST"
});

export const postRequest = (url, payload = {}) => client.request({ url, data: payload });

const res = await postRequest('/login', body)
```